# Rendering quad with tiling image?

Tags: opengl, qt5

I am learning how to texture a quad in OpenGL. The idea is to have the image repeated across the whole quad, nevertheless I am getting the image stretched and the two triangles forming the quad are visible.

What am I missing? The code looks like follows

```
void GLViewer::initializeGL()
{
    float vertices[] =
    {
        -0.5, 0.0, 0.0,
         0.5, 0.0, 0.0,
         0.5, 0.5, 0.0
    };

    // Setup viewport
    glViewport(0, 0,this->width(), this->height());

    // OpenGL configuration
    glClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);

    // Setup shaders
    m_triangleShader.addShaderFromSourceFile(QGLShader::Vertex, ":/vshader.glsl");
    m_triangleShader.addShaderFromSourceFile(QGLShader::Fragment, ":/fshader.glsl");
    m_triangleShader.link();

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &m_VAO);
    glBindVertexArray(m_VAO);

    glPointSize(10);

    glGenBuffers(1, &m_VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    float quad[] =
    {
        -1.0, -1.0,
         1.0, -1.0,
        -1.0,  1.0,
         1.0,  1.0
    };

    float uv[] =
    {
        0.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 1.0
    };

    m_backgroundShader.addShaderFromSourceFile(QGLShader::Vertex, ":/vbackground.glsl");
    m_backgroundShader.addShaderFromSourceFile(QGLShader::Fragment, ":/fbackground.glsl");
    m_backgroundShader.link();
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &m_backgroundVAO);
    glBindVertexArray(m_backgroundVAO);

    glGenBuffers(1, &m_quadVBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_quadVBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(quad), quad, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glGenBuffers(1, &m_uvVBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_uvVBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(uv), uv, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glGenTextures(1, &m_textureID);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_textureID);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    QImage image(":/background.png");
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, image.width(), image.height(),
                 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image.bits());

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

void GLViewer::paintGL()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    m_backgroundShader.bind();
    glBindVertexArray(m_backgroundVAO);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_textureID);
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(m_backgroundShader.programId(),"tex"),0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,0,4);

    m_triangleShader.bind();
    glBindVertexArray(m_VAO);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    update();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you expect your texture to be repeated (and how many times) by the code you are using?

However, the code as-is is consistent with your observation. You are using the texcoords in the range [0,1], so if you are not tweaking the texcoords before sampling the texture, you should only see the image strechted to the quads.  You *might* do that via the shaders you have not pasted so far. If you want the texture to appear `n`-times tiled along the `u` dimension and `m` times along `v`, you need to use `[0,n]` for the `u` range and `[0,m]` for the `v` range, respectively.

The second issue is that your texcoords do not match your geometry. This is probably causing what you describe as "the two triangles forming the quad are visible". Your two trianges  do not build up the quad *in texture space* you'd expect, you should swap the last two lines:

> ```
> float uv[] =
> {
>     0.0, 0.0,
>     1.0, 0.0,
>     1.0, 1.0,      /* should be 0.0, 1.0 */
>     0.0, 1.0       /* should be 1.0, 1.0 */
> };
> ```

Comment: I can actually force tiling without making shader stuff if I just let my `uv` coordinates be bigger than the range [0,0]x[1,1].