# Why isn't the triangle rendered on top of textured quad?

Tags: opengl

With the same code as in my previous question [Rendering quad with tiling image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27301998/rendering-quad-with-tiling-image/27302245#27302245) I don't understand why the triangle is not being rendered on top of the textured quad.

Can someone point out what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have depth test enabled which defaults to less (only pixels that are closer get drawn).

If you want a background then disable depth writing during the first pass.

```
void GLViewer::paintGL()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    m_backgroundShader.bind();
    glBindVertexArray(m_backgroundVAO);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_textureID);
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(m_backgroundShader.programId(),"tex"),0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,0,4);

    glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    m_triangleShader.bind();
    glBindVertexArray(m_VAO);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    update();
}
```